# Need assistance with blit function

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a new game in pygame and the blit function just is not working for me, it should be simple but I just don't know what's wrong.

```
import pygame
import sys
pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
game = True
WIDTH = 160
HEIGHT = 144
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
level = pygame.image.load('RBYG/Level.png')
def redrawGameWindow():
    screen.blit(level, (0, 0))
    
while game:
    screen.blit(level,(0, 0))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        print(event)
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                sys.exit()
    redrawGameWindow()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Answer (score 2):

You're missing `pygame.display.flip()`, you have to do that after you blit or nothing will happen. Your `redrawGameWindow()` function should flip the display. Also, you're calling `screen.blit(level, (0, 0))` twice in your main loop, which may be unnecessary; try just keeping one of them (just make sure to `flip()` after).

Comment: Also don't forget to pass in the `screen` var to the `redrawGameWindow` method - never use implicit global variables (if it has to be a global, use the global keyword)

Comment: And if it has to be global, still don't make it global but make a Game class instead that holds the appropriate attributes (`self.screen` for example).